# Undefined variable 'count'

Tags: php, laravel

I haven't done PHP in a while so I'm a bit confused why I am getting the error in the title

```
$count =0;
User::chunk(200, function ($users) {
    $count++;
    error_log('------------ chunck: '.$count);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `use`, described in docs(http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such
>   variables must be declared in the function header. Inheriting
>   variables from the parent scope is not the same as using global
>   variables. Global variables exist in the global scope, which is the
>   same no matter what function is executing.

Code:

```
$count =0;
User::chunk(200, function ($users) use($count) {
    $count++;
    error_log('------------ chunck: '.$count);
});
```

Comment: just added some more detail

Answer (score 4):

you should use   use ($count) for pass the var $count to the anonymous function

```
  $count =0;
 User::chunk(200, function ($users) use ($count) {
  $count++;
   error_log('------------ chunck: '.$count);
});
```

see more here  http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php